# How to print a line from a file that has the exact same index of the student?

Tags: c, file

I have students in file with first name,last name and index.

This is my txt file:

```
Jon Wick 1569
Mark Jones 1489
Mike Miler 2050
```

I want the user to input an index number and program should print the line with same index of student.

this is my code:

```
    char ch;
    int index;
    FILE *pfile;

    pfile = fopen("student.txt","r");
    printf("Enter index of student: ");
    scanf("%d",&index);
    while((ch = fgetc(pfile)) != EOF){
        ...
    }

    fclose(pfile);
```

Comment: First off, read the file line-by-line, not character-by-character.

Comment: Use `strchr` to search the input into the current read line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do this by:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    FILE* file = fopen("student.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
      printf ("File cannot open\n");
      return 1;
    }
    char line[256];
    int index,search;
    printf("Please enter the student index?\n");
    scanf("%d", &search);
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
        sscanf(line,"%*[^0-9]%d",&index);
        if(search == index)
        {
            printf("%s", line);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

If I didn't, add a comment below and I will try to improve my answer. It reads file line by line and then get integer form the line. That is student index. Compare it with the search value, if it satisfy. Then print it print that line.

Comment: You should check that the `fopen()` succeeds.  You should also explain what you've done.

Comment: Thank you so much, the code works and that is exactly what I needed :)

Comment: You'd better hope nobody has a digit in their name :)

Comment: @ScottHunter yes.